# C# Database Inserting Data

Tags: c#

If a textbox is empty, and I am inserting data into the database, how do you show a messagebox?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "insert into Ученики (Имя,Класс,Группа) values ('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perform a check on the textbox before the try.

Comment: How about checking your textbox `Text` property instead? And checking `ExecuteNonQuery` returns bigger than zero or not? Can you please clarify your question? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Bigger than zero and only letters

Comment: Use parameterized queries, please! It's much safer and easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the value of the textbox is empty:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)) 
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Ученики (Имя,Класс,Группа) values ('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("textbox2 was empty!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that each textbox has a value.

```
private void button1_Click()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text)
    { 
        MesageBox.Show(@"Please enter text into each box.");
        return;
    }

    // if all textboxes have values then call update the database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call an alert box using javascript.

ASPX Page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkTextBoxEmpty() {
    if (document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientId %>').value == "") {
        alert("TextBox Empty.");
    }
}
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:checkTextBoxEmpty();")
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "insert into Ученики (Имя,Класс,Группа) values ('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    }
}
```